# What happens to an invisible stalker when it's killed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planes

When an [invisible stalker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/invisible-stalker) is killed, is it gone, or does it return again to fulfill its mission?  I read that it would return to its elemental plane when killed on the material plane.  Is it still under its summoner's commands then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes it's gone. You killed it.

> When it is defeated or the magic that binds it expires, an invisible stalker vanishes in a gust of wind

Neither Invisible Stalkers nor Air Elementals are immortal in the same way that devils are. There is no requirement that you kill them on their own plane. By "vanishes" they mean it dies without leaving a corpse because its made of air.

Answer (score 4):

## It is no longer under its summoner's command

The *Monster Manual* entry for the [invisible stalker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-i#InvisibleStalker) reads (*MM* page 192, emphasis mine):

> An invisible stalker is an air elemental that has been summoned from its native plane and transformed by powerful magic. Its sole purpose is to hunt down creatures and retrieve objects for its summoner. **When it is defeated or the magic that binds it expires, an invisible stalker vanishes in a gust of wind**.
>
> ***Directed Hunter.*** When an invisible stalker is created, it stays at its summoner's side until it is given a task to perform. If an assignment doesn't involve hunting down and slaying a specific creature or recovering an object, the magic that created the invisible stalker ends and the elemental is released. Otherwise, it completes the task, then returns to its summoner for more commands, forced to serve until the magic that binds it expires. If its summoner dies in the interim, the invisible stalker vanishes after completing its task.
>
> An invisible stalker is an unwilling servant at best. It resents any undertaking assigned to it. A mission that requires significant time might drive the invisible stalker to pervert the intent of a command unless it is worded carefully.

I am not sure where you read that it would return to its plane when killed, as I do not read that in the invisible stalker section, or in the section on [elementals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-e#Elementals). However, it appears clear from this text that **if defeated, the invisible stalker vanishes and is no longer under its summoner's command**.